# ObjectDataSource - handle CRUD errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

What is the nice way of extending **ObjectDataSource** in order to handle CRUD errors. I know that there are events created, deleted, etc. that can have handlers that check **e.Exception** & **e.ExceptionHandled**, but I am not keen on repeating the same delegates over and over on all CRUD forms. I was thinking about inheriting from **ObjectDataSource**, any other ideas?

Thanks,Paweł

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sound like a plan, and than internally subscribe to the events you need.
Another way is to have a method that creates the `ObjectDataSource` (and subscribes to the events) that you use instead of creating it yourself.

```
public static ObjectDataSource CreateObjectDataSource()
{
   var obj = new ObjectDataSource();
   obj.Deleted  += OnDeleted; //function for handling event
   ...

   return obj;
}
```